# ValueError: could not convert string to float from a file which is a list written in a file

Tags: python, list, floating-point

I'm writing a program to compute the sum of squares of a list of strings that are numbers read from a file. The functions work when not used on a file, which confuses me even more.

The file is a simple list ["1", "2", "3"]

After running the program I get an error:

*ValueError: could not convert string to float: '["1","2","3"]'*

Here's the code:

```
def toNumbers(strList):
    newList = []
    for i in strList:
        i = float(i)
        newList.append(i)
    return newList

def squareEach(nums):
    newList = []
    for i in nums:
        i = i**2
        newList.append(i)
    return newList

def sumList(nums):
    count = 0
    for i in nums:
        count += i
    return count

def main():
    file = open("listOfSquares", "r")
    f = file.readlines()
    print(sumList(squareEach(toNumbers(f))))
 
main()
```

Comment: If your file literally contains `["1", "2", "3"]` this is seen as a string: a sequence of characters including `[` and `"` etc. It is not read as a list. You'll have to do some string parsing to extract the numbers from the string first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error because getLines returns a list of lines so when you iterate over values in toNumbers method you actually iterate over a list with single element - the whole first line from the file - instead of individual numbers.

To iterate over numbers you have to first take this first line and split it into indovidual numbers, for example using split method https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp

Answer (score 0):

That's because the text file is just a plain text - there are no variables. The best thing with a given code is to split it by `[]`.

```
f = [''.join(''.join(x.split('[')).split(']')) for x in f]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you search for numbers in a file you should use re in order to read the "list" (**it actully a string**). Moreover, you can find any number in this file with re.

```
import re

#this is the pattern for finding numbers in a string
p = re.compile(r"[0.0-9.0]+")

st = '["1", "22.1", "3"]' #the string

nums = p.findall(st) #search for a float number and create a list of ['1','22.1','3']

nums = [float(num) for num in nums] #converte the numbers from str type to float type
```